# Application Virtualization Risk Through WAN / Internet

Tags: networking, security, virtualization

I was weighing pros and cons about the new mission critical system that through application virtualization, will allow my colleagues from 3 different countries to access it.

***Here are some background information.***

1) The new mission critical system contain two servers. The system server which will host the SQL database will be place in the trusted zone. The application virtualization server will be place in the DMZ.

2) While the local colleagues should be able to access the SQL database through an application program installed on their computer PC, the overseas colleague will be connection to the DMZ application virtualization server for connection to the system server.

3) In order for my overseas colleagues to access the virtualize application, I will have to assign a public IP address to the DMZ application virtualization server, opening only 1 port for it.

***Question***

While opening only one port for this particular public IP address seems to be restrictive enough, I am wondering can if the streaming of the virtualize application is protected by some form of encryption, similar to how any VPN work?

Reason why I am asking this is because the application virtualization server is using an application that I have never heard of and no one can ever Google it.

Why is the industry standard for application virtualization aross the internet / WAN?

Answer (score 0):

The communication over the Internet may, or may not, be encrypted.  It all depends on the protocol which it uses.  Even if it is encrypted, unless it's a widely used, heavily scrutinised protocol that is maintained and adapted according to new cryptographic findings, there's a good chance that it is horribly, horribly broken and insecure.

The industry standard for application virtualisation over the Internet is to put a standard, well-maintained VPN server in front, enable two-factor authentication on the VPN, and then *also* firewall the connectivity between the VPN server and the application virtualisation platform, because endpoints are always getting broken into.

If your application may be attractive as a *specific* target, then you want to do even more work, like implementing strong and highly restrictive DLP (Data-Loss Prevention), anomaly detection, and content-level restrictions on the data and network, so as to minimise the damage that will result when someone inevitably pops your system open like a grape and squeezes out the juicy data within.